# Unable to increment value based on 'wheel' event listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increment a variable based off whether someone scrolls down the page, or scrolls up the page.

The event fires everytime you scroll either up or down, but the value only increments once. Do you guys have an idea why this is?

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
  const y = e.deltaY;
  let scrollIndex = 0;
  if (y > 0) {
    scrollIndex++;
  } else {
    scrollIndex--;
  }
  console.log(`Scroll index: ${scrollIndex}`);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! your `let scrollIndex = 0;` should be outside the function so you can safely add/subtract, as you wrote it, it will always reset to `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you every time set new `scrollIndex` variable and equal it to zero. Put `scrollIndex` outside the function and it will work. Example:

```
let scrollIndex = 0;
window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
  const y = e.deltaY;

  if (y > 0) {
    scrollIndex++;
  } else {
    scrollIndex--;
  }
  console.log(`Scroll index: ${scrollIndex}`);
});
```